# How do I combine rows of a tibble with the same row name but unique values?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following tibble:

```
  Symbol `Annotated Term`                           
  <chr>  <chr>                                      
1 H2aj   chromatin silencing                        
2 Sfpq   histone H3 deacetylation                   
3 Ube2n  histone ubiquitination                     
4 Ube2n  positive regulation of histone modification
```

How do I combine the repeated symbols into one row, and have their annotated terms grouped together in the same row so that the above tibble looks like:

```
  Symbol `Annotated Term`                           
  <chr>  <chr>                                      
1 H2aj   chromatin silencing                        
2 Sfpq   histone H3 deacetylation                   
3 Ube2n  histone ubiquitination, positive regulation of histone modification
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Please supply your example data in a format that can be copied and pasted(e.g. as the output from ```dput()```).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends. If you want the strings to be concatenated and unified into single strings, then

```r
opt1 <- aggregate(`Annotated Term` ~ Symbol, data = dat, FUN = toString)
opt1
#   Symbol                                                      Annotated Term
# 1   H2aj                                                 chromatin silencing
# 2   Sfpq                                            histone H3 deacetylation
# 3  Ube2n histone ubiquitination, positive regulation of histone modification
str(opt1)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ Symbol        : chr  "H2aj" "Sfpq" "Ube2n"
#  $ Annotated Term: chr  "chromatin silencing" "histone H3 deacetylation" "histone ubiquitination, positive regulation of histone modification"
```

If you want them to be easily split later, then your `` `Annotated Term` `` column needs to be kept as a list-column, in which case:

```r
opt2 <- aggregate(`Annotated Term` ~ Symbol, data = dat, FUN = list)
opt2
#   Symbol                                                      Annotated Term
# 1   H2aj                                                 chromatin silencing
# 2   Sfpq                                            histone H3 deacetylation
# 3  Ube2n histone ubiquitination, positive regulation of histone modification
str(opt2)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ Symbol        : chr  "H2aj" "Sfpq" "Ube2n"
#  $ Annotated Term:List of 3
#   ..$ : chr "chromatin silencing"
#   ..$ : chr "histone H3 deacetylation"
#   ..$ : chr  "histone ubiquitination" "positive regulation of histone modification"
```

(If you don't already know about list-columns and believe you will not be interesting in un-combining them later, then I recommend `opt1`.)

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Symbol = c("H2aj", "Sfpq", "Ube2n", "Ube2n"), `Annotated Term` = c("chromatin silencing", "histone H3 deacetylation",     "histone ubiquitination", "positive regulation of histone modification")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

As the OP's data is `tibble`, we can make use of `tidyverse` methods.  Grouped by 'Symbol' and `paste/str_c` the 'Annotated Term'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Symbol) %>%
   summarise(`Annotated Term` = str_c(`Annotated Term`,
                    collapse=", "), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# Symbol `Annotated Term`                           
#  <chr>  <chr>                                      
#1 H2aj   chromatin silencing                        
#2 Sfpq   histone H3 deacetylation                   
#3 Ube2n  histone ubiquitination, positive regulation of histone modification
```

---

Or in `base R`, we can use `aggregate` with `paste`

```
aggregate(`Annotated Term` ~ Symbol, df1, FUN = paste, collapse=", ")
```

---

Or we can also have as a `list` column

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Symbol) %>%
   summarise(`Annotated Term` = list(`Annotated Term`), .groups = 'drop')
```

NOTE: No wrapper functions used

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Symbol = c("H2aj", "Sfpq", "Ube2n", "Ube2n"), 
    `Annotated Term` = c("chromatin silencing", "histone H3 deacetylation", 
    "histone ubiquitination ", "positive regulation of histone modification"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Tibbles do not have row names but assuming you mean that you want to combine rows with the same value in the `Symbol` column and that `Annnotated Term` should be a character vector in the output, use `toString`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Symbol) %>%
  summarize(`Annotated Term` = toString(`Annotated Term`), .groups = "drop")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Symbol `Annotated Term`                                                   
  <chr>  <chr>                                                              
1 H2aj   chromatin silencing                                                
2 Sfpq   histone H3 deacetylation                                           
3 Ube2n  histone ubiquitination, positive regulation of histone modification
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
dat <- structure(list(Symbol = c("H2aj", "Sfpq", "Ube2n", "Ube2n"), 
`Annotated Term` = c("chromatin silencing", "histone H3 deacetylation", 
"histone ubiquitination", "positive regulation of histone modification"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```